# List of list to list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of this type 
   `p = {{y, 1, 3}, {x, 2, 0}, {z, 3, 1/(k + 1)}}`

I can use a Do loop that is

```
    `In: T = {}; Do[AppendTo[T, p[[i]][[1]] -> p[[i]][[2]]  p[[i]][[1]] + p[[i]][[3]]], {i, Length[p]}]
    In: T 
    Out: {y -> 3 + y, x -> 2 x, z -> 1/(1 + k) + 3 z}`
```

Is there I way I can archive the same output without the Do loop?

Answer (score 7):

The one-liner is

```
(#1 -> #2 #1 + #3 &) @@@ p
```

I recommend studying
[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)
[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)
And particularly these answers to the second question:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/26956
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/26956

Comment: Output corrected.

Comment: @evansdoe likewise, the response.