# Convert a list of lists into a list of rules

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation, rule

I have some trouble converting an imported list looking like this:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
```

into a list of rules looking like this:

```
{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}
```

Comment: It is a list of **lists** of rules. But anyway: `List@*Rule@@@...`

Comment: Thx. So like this? data = {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}} data@*Rule@@@ ?

Comment: `List@*Rule@@@data`

Comment: Thx. It worked too.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88429 is a very similar question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
Rule @@@ list
```

> `{a -> b, c -> d, e -> f}`

This will work as well as

```
{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}
```

in just about every situation where you are likely need a list of rules.

Of course, if you must have the particular form that you show, there is

```
{#1 -> #2} & @@@ list
```

and

```
{#[[1]] -> #[[2]]} & /@ list
```

and

```
List @* Rule @@@ list
```

and

```
List @@@ Rule @@@ list
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
list1 = {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}};
list2 = Table[{list[[i, 1]] -> list[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

prints out

```
{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}
```

Comment: Thx. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[List @* Rule] @ list
```

{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Using `Cases`;

```
Cases[list, v_ :> List@*Rule @@ v]

(*{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}*)
```

Or using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[List@Rule[#1, #2] &, Thread@#] &@list

(*{{a -> b}, {c -> d}, {e -> f}}*)
```